# How to load datetime value from a string in FileDateTime format in powershell?

Tags: powershell, datetime

```
Get-Date -Format FileDateTime
```

gives something like this:

```
20211027T1306219297
```

Is it possible to import such a string into a datetime variable?
Something like?

```
$date = Get-Date "20211027T1306219297"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *[`[datetime]::ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)* method with *`yyyyMMddTHHmmssffff`* as format argument.

```
$date = [datetime]::ParseExact("20211027T1306219297", 'yyyyMMddTHHmmssffff', $null)
```

This is because *`FileDateTime`* internally uses *`yyyyMMddTHHmmssffff`* format which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.1).

> **FileDateTime**.
>
> A file or path-friendly representation of the current date and time in
> local time, in 24-hour format. The format is *`yyyyMMddTHHmmssffff`*
> (case-sensitive, using a 4-digit year, 2-digit month, 2-digit day, the
> letter T as a time separator, 2-digit hour, 2-digit minute, 2-digit
> second, and 4-digit millisecond). For example: 20190627T0840107271.